# How to autocomplete SQL field based on same row fields

Tags: sql, ssms

QUESTION HAS BEEN UPDATED:
Let's say I have two tables:
Table1
`ID_Ticket | Ticket_Quantity  |  Total_Price(Calculated field)
    --------------------------------------------
     2     |     5            |  x
     1     |     3            |  y`
Table2
`ID_Ticket        |  Ticket_Price
    ------------------------
            1     |  4.5
            2     |  5`

I want to prevent the user of the database to fill the field of Total_Price (via Edit Top 200 Rows or queries), instead I want it to be calculated as Ticket_Price * Ticket_Quantity and be inserted automatically on that row.
 In this case, **x should be 25** and **y should be 13.5** (the values should be insterted automatically once Ticket_Quantity and Ticket_Price are filled for that row)
I wrote a function like this:
 
`CREATE FUNCTION Multiply(@x DECIMAL(19,4), @y DECIMAL (19,4))
RETURNS DECIMAL(19,4)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @x * Ticket_Price 
   FROM Table2 
   WHERE ID_Ticket = @y
END`
But there is an error:
*Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client*
 Also when I want to add the calculated field based on the function:
`ALTER TABLE Purchases
ADD Total_Price AS Multiply(Table2.Ticket_Price,Ticket_Quantity);` 
 The query doesn't execute and gives me this error:
*The multi-part identifier "Product.Prod_Price" could not be bound.*

How should I call the values from Table2 and fix the Multiply function?

Comment: Use Stored Procedure to insert records in your database, do not publish your tables. Never. Use read only views to publish information.

Comment: Make it a calculated field.

Comment: @McNets my apology. With user I meant the database manager (who can use the database and modify it)

Comment: Which DataBase are you talking about?

Comment: @DanBracuk does it get autocompleted every time I enter new data, or do I have to execute the calculation manually? Also can the calculated field be modified directly, allowing different values than the sum of its parent fields? I never heard of calculated fields before.

Comment: Your google search string is `sql server sql server calculated column`

Comment: @DanBracuk I've searched about functions, but I am a little stuck.Would you mind looking at the updated question and help me out? I'd appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, so I'll post it for future readers who have the same problem:

In the Object Explorer (left panel) go to this path:
`Databases --> <your_database_name> --> programmability --> functions`
Right-click on the Functions folder and select `New --> Scalar-valued function`
Paste the following function script (replace < variables > with those that correspond to your database):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Multiply(@id INT, @price DECIMAL(19,4))
--or (@x float, @y money) depending on the type of your columns you have
RETURNS DECIMAL(19,4)
--RETURNS <data_type_of_the_calculated_column_you_want>
AS 
BEGIN
   RETURN 
   (SELECT @price * Ticket_Price
   --SELECT @<second_argument/column_name_of_Table1>*<column_name_of_Table2>
   FROM Table2
   --FROM <your_Table2_name> 
   WHERE ID_Ticket = @id)
   --WHERE <unique/PrimaryKey_Column_to_identify_the_row_in_Table2>
   -- = @<ForeignKey_Column_to_identify_the_row_in_Table2>
END
```

And execute it.
Now Create a new query (Ctrl+N) to add the calculated column in `Table1`, and copy-paste the following query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Table1
--ALTER TABLE <your_Table1_name>
ADD Total_Price AS dbo.Multiply(ID_Ticket,Ticket_Quantity);
--ADD <name_of_the_calculated_row_you_like> AS
--   dbo.<Function_Name>(<id_column_name_of_Table2>,<column_name_from_Table1>)
```

Execute the query.
Now the calculated column should be the multiplication of the columns of Table1 and Table2